# Is there any way to add new theme for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, themes

Is there  Any way or does anyone know how to add a new theme to Windows 8?  I want to load new themes for Windows 8. Other than its default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a shared theme. These have the extension `.themepack`.

All you need to do is open this file and Windows will install the theme. You can then choose it from the list of available ones.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-themes)

There are official themes on the Microsoft site in their [Personalisation Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/themes).

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously download `.themepacks` from many [sources](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/themes) which can only change the wallpaper, screensaver, colors etc.

But, you can also install 3rd party themes which customize every aspect of Windows:

[image: Theme]

1. Patch the `UxTheme.dll` file using [this](http://www.uxstyle.com/) tool and restart your PC.
2. Find some 3rd party themes. [deviantART](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/skins/?q=windows%208%20rtm%20themes) is a good source:
3. Download the theme and copy all the files to `%windir%\Resources\Themes`.
4. Select the theme from the Personalization window. Now you will be able to see the custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can download themes made by 3rd parties. Usually there's a .exe file or a .theme file (maybe another extension need to check) that you have to execute to add a new theme.